# jquery jTable - Dialog Close Button Theme Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-jtable

I am having an issue with the jquery jTable theme.  I am using the metro blue theme and all seems to render correctly except the close button graphic on the dialog boxes.  See screen shots of the dialogs and my javascript includes. Any ideas on what could be wrong here would be helpful.  I tried creating a new theme to no avail so it might be the order i am including the css and javascript files?  Any ideas on how to debug this would be very much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You add this css codes to your theme :

```css
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.ui-button-icon-only .ui-icon {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```